# Why is $(this).val() giving me the value from this first method in this second method?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The $(this).val() in the second method returns the same value that I get in the first method.  I expected to get the first value of the fields with the secondGroup class.  What am I doing wrong?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  jQuery.validator.addMethod("method1", function(value, element, options) {
        .....some code here....
  var elems = $(element).parents('form').find(options[0]);
      jQuery.each(elems, function(){ 
      thisVal = $(this).val();
      });
        .....some code here......
}, jQuery.format("some message."));

  jQuery.validator.addMethod("method2", function(value, element, options) {
        .....some code here....
  var elems = $(element).parents('form').find(options[0]);
      jQuery.each(elems, function(){ 
      thisVal = $(this).val();
      });
        .....some code here......
}, jQuery.format("some message."));


 $("#formName").validate({

 rules: {
   firstMethod1:{
       method1: ['.firstGroup']
   },
   secondMethod1:{
       method1: ['.firstGroup']
   },
   thirdMethod1:{
       method1: ['.firstGroup']
   },
   firstMethod2:{
       method2: ['.secondGroup']
   },
   secondMethod2:{
       method2: ['.secondGroup']
   },
   thirdMethod2:{
       method2: ['.secondGroup']
   }

   }
 });

});
```

Comment: Doesn't `var elems = $(element).parents('form').find(options[0]);` that find the same form each time and just loop through the same values thus outputting the same each time?

Comment: options[0] is different for each method.  It has a value of '.firstGroup' or '.secondGroup'.

Comment: make a jsFiddle, please with the simplest example causing problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `jQuery.each()` instead of `.each()`.

Use:

```
elems.each(function(){ 
    thisVal = $(this).val(); 
});
```